# repaint is not calling paintComponent

Tags: java, swing

Repaint is not calling PaintComponent.
 I tried to call it from another method of the Try class too but it did not work out.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Try extends JPanel {
    int i =0;

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
       //super.paintComponent(g);
       System.out.println("hey");
   }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       JFrame f=new JFrame();
       Try t = new Try();
       f.setSize(500,600);//400 width and 500 height

       Container contentPane = f.getContentPane();
       contentPane.add(new PaintComponent());
       f.setVisible(true);//making the frame visible

       while(true){
          t.repaint();
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant `contentPane.add(new Try())`. Also, _don't_ block  the EDT; _do_ see [*Concurrency in Swing*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [*How to Use Swing Timers*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Comment: And don't remove the `super.paintComponent()` line, follow the [Swing's custom painting tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step1.html) to know how it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues some of which are mentioned by @trashgod in comments.

1. You are calling repaint on the instance which you did NOT add to the content pane - you have a different one there (actually, you have something completely different there - `new PaintComponent()`).
2. Do not remove `super.paintComponent ( g );` unless you clean up the area on your own (pretty much fill the whole component background if it is opaque), otherwise you will get visual glitches on such components upon repaint.
3. You are spamming repaint operations which is extremely bad, make at least some delay between the repaints giving Swing time to perform the repaints. The best case is if you repaint component only when it actually will display something different visually. If you need to update the view all the time - at least limit it to 30-60 frames (repaints) per second. Also, some internal Swing optimizations might "eat" some of the repaint calls, so expect that you might not see as many `paintComponent` calls as a number of repaints you call on the component.
4. You are working with Swing components outside of Event Dispatch Thread (shortly EDT) which might cause issues. Make sure you always use it to create Swing components and call any methods on them. `SwingUtilities` helps with that.
5. Any heavy operations that take a long time (or unknown time) to be completed should be executed outside of EDT, otherwise, your UI will simply hang while you are waiting for that operation to complete because all UI updates are performed on EDT and not anywhere else.

Considering all I said above, this is how your example should look like:

```
public class Try extends JPanel
{
    @Override
    public void paintComponent ( final Graphics g )
    {
        super.paintComponent ( g );

        final Graphics2D g2d = ( Graphics2D ) g;
        g2d.drawString ( Long.toString ( System.currentTimeMillis () ), 25, 35 );

        System.out.println ( "repainted" );
    }

    public static void main ( final String[] args )
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater ( new Runnable ()
        {
            @Override
            public void run ()
            {
                final JFrame f = new JFrame ();

                final Try t = new Try ();
                f.getContentPane ().add ( t );

                f.setSize ( 500, 600 );
                f.setVisible ( true );

                new Thread ( new Runnable ()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run ()
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            while ( true )
                            {
                                t.repaint ();
                                Thread.sleep ( 25 );
                            }
                        }
                        catch ( final InterruptedException e )
                        {
                            //
                        }
                    }
                } ).start ();
            }
        } );
    }
}
```

Hope that clarifies it a bit for you.

There is also `SwingWorker` class that helps to perform long-running tasks in Swing, but I didn't use it here to keep the example as simple as possible.

Also a side note - you do not need to call `repaint ()` within EDT because it sends the repaint request to EDT on its own, so that method is safe to use on any thread (like I do in the example).

Comment: Thanks for the example @Mikle